# unattended-upgrades not doing anything with ESM, even though security updates are available

Tags: unattended-upgrades

Ubuntu 18.04 with a Pro token:

```
$ sudo  pro security-status
763 packages installed:
    680 packages from Ubuntu Main/Restricted repository
    57 packages from Ubuntu Universe/Multiverse repository
    26 packages from third parties

To get more information about the packages, run
    pro security-status --help
for a list of available options.

The system apt cache may be outdated. Make sure to run
    sudo apt-get update
to get the latest package information from apt.

This machine is attached to an Ubuntu Pro subscription.

Main/Restricted packages are receiving security updates from
Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-infra' enabled until 2028. There are 72 pending security updates.

Universe/Multiverse packages are receiving security updates from
Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled until 2028. There are 10 pending security updates.
```

But unattended-upgrades does nothing:

```
$ sudo unattended-upgrade -v
Initial blacklisted packages: 
Initial whitelisted packages: 
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=bionic, o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=bionic
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

We don't want to run a full `sudo apt upgrade`.

I verified the unattended-upgrades configuration too:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
        // Extended Security Maintenance; doesn't necessarily exist for
        // every release and this system may not have it installed, but if
        // available, the policy for updates is such that unattended-upgrades
        // should also install from here by default.
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* earlier this year (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Those lines should say         `"${distro_id}ESMApps:${distro_codename}-apps-security";
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-infra-security";` At least they do in 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}";
```

It should be:

```
        "${distro_id}ESMApps:${distro_codename}-apps-security";
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-infra-security";
```

Comment: That worked. I wonder why the conf file has the incorrect value. It's the default file from Ubuntu.

Comment: The corrected version is the default. Test for yourself using a LiveUSB. We don't know when or why yours was changed.